# Resizing images and uploading blobs faster to windows azure using WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am trying to build a windows phone app to upload images to azure storage. I am current using the nuget package - Windows Azure Storage Client Library for Windows Phone and the sample to code to upload images but images take forever to upload. I tired resizing the images before I upload them. However I need to convert the image to a bitmap before I could resize it after that I don't how can I change it back to the photostream to upload it to azure?

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

//Initialize and load your image.
var myImage = new WriteableBitmap();
int newWidth, newHeight;
var resizedImage = myImage.ResizeBicubic(newWidth, newHeight);
```

How could I go about resizing images and uploading it to windows azure and are there any other ways to speed up the upload process?